# how to replace properties of all objects in collection in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

suppose i have collection

```
[
      {"name" : "full-name", "value" : "W. Chandry"},
      {"name" : "email", "value" : "wchandry@example.org"},
      {"name" : "blog", "value" : "http://example.org/blogs/wchandry"},
      {"name" : "avatar", "value" : "http://example.org/images/wchandry"}
]
```

i want to change the value of all "value" property to "TBD" so that it becomes this

```
[
      {"name" : "full-name", "value" : "TBD"},
      {"name" : "email", "value" : "TBD"},
      {"name" : "blog", "value" : "TBD"},
      {"name" : "avatar", "value" : "TBD"}
]
```

what would be the best way to achieve this in underscore.js or javascript

Comment: Just iterate the objects and update the property of each one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need underscore. You can simply loop over the array and just change the properties on each object.

```
collection.forEach(function(item) {
  item.value = 'TBD';
});
```

Running example:

```js
var collection = [{
  "name": "full-name",
  "value": "W. Chandry"
}, {
  "name": "email",
  "value": "wchandry@example.org"
}, {
  "name": "blog",
  "value": "http://example.org/blogs/wchandry"
}, {
  "name": "avatar",
  "value": "http://example.org/images/wchandry"
}];

collection.forEach(function(item) {
  item.value = 'TBD';
});

collection.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

If you also need to take into account array-like structures, your can use a regular `for` loop or the [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead:

```
[].forEach.call(collection, function(item) {
  item.value = 'TBD';
});
```

Comment: I think for this you need to add `ng-repeat` in your template

Comment: The OP just asked how to update a certain property of all objects in an array... didn't specify anything angular-related.

Comment: Note `forEach` is already intentionally generic, it's not required to be called on an array. For array-like objects you can borrow it like `[].forEach.call(arrayLike, func)`.

Comment: @nem Before the edit the answer was already OK, since in this case it's a real array, `forEach` can be used directly. I just wanted to add a note, not make a correction.

Comment: @Oriol yeah, I see that now, I acted before processing what I've read haha. Think I covered all cases now.

Answer (score -2):

You could use lodash.js to achieve this

_.merge(arr, {prop:'Val'});
_.assign(arr, {prop:'Val'});

Comment: There should be something similar in underscore as well

Comment: Anything other than vanilla JS to simply loop over an array of objects and change a value for each one is _extreme_ overkill.